# chromium-browser: ERROR: not connected to the gnome-3-28-1804 content interface

Tags: snap, chromium

my launcher for chromium stopped working recently.  i thought i'd try it at the command-line and I saw this:

```
  chromium-browser                     
ERROR: not connected to the gnome-3-28-1804 content interface.
```

(this is on groovy/20.10)

Comment: I had the same problem, using this solution worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178161/snaps-are-not-launching-or-failing-to-install

Answer (score 12):

OK I found this solution on [the snapcraft.io forum](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/error-not-connected-to-the-gnome-3-28-1804-content-interface/23342/3)

```
snap connect chromium:gnome-3-28-1804 gnome-3-28-1804:gnome-3-28-1804
```

doesn't output anything but after I ran it, chromium ran again happily.

I'd love to know why it got broken tho!

Comment: I got this error : error: snap "gnome-3-28-1804" has no slot named "gnome-3-28-1804"

Comment: @hwjp Your `snap connect` command gives me this error : `error: cannot communicate with server: timeout exceeded while waiting for response`

Comment: snaps sure make life difficult

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue in my ubuntu 21.04 after installing chromium browser and tried to run chromium.
To install and run chromium first remove the installed version either in ubuntu software center or using terminal

```
sudo apt-get remove chromium-browser
```

Restart your machine.
After successfull reboot open ubuntu software center and search for chromium and install it. This installation from software center has no issue.

Answer (score 1):

The chromium-browser package, as its doc says is...

> "...a transitional dummy package. It can safely be removed.
> chromium-browser is now replaced by the chromium snap."

I solved this issue by removing the snap

```
$ snap remove chormium
```

and reinstalling it:

```
$ snap install chromium
```

And chromium works again.

Comment: To anyone stumbling upon this please keep in mind that this also deletes ALL associated user data as well, including bookmarks, history, session data, you name it. Yes, snap really IS crap like that.

Comment: this is so dumb. Can snap fix an installation automatically?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. I figured out which "gnome-X-YY-ZZZZ"-package should be installed as follows.

1. Run `snap find gnome`
2. Find the gnome package that is showing as: gnome-XXXX. In my case it was: gnome-2048.
3. Install this gnome-XXXX package.

Answer (score 0):

try to install `gnome-3-28-1804`

```
snap install gnome-3-28-1804
```