# Chromium snaps slot not connected

Tags: snap, chromium

A recent update shut chromium down
I get this error when running "chromium-browser" in the terminal window

Content snap command-chain for /snap/chromium/2529/gnome-platform/command-chain/desktop-launch not found: ensure slot is connected

How do I fix its slot so it connects?

Comment: You've not provided your OS/release details (*not actually that useful for snap packages; but rarely go wrong as `firefox` for example on some releases uses a different channel to other releases by default!, I don't think that applies to `chromium`*) but I'll suggest adding a `snap info chromium` to your question too.  You can connect slots via `snap connect` for example which maybe a means to fix.  `snap connections chromium`   (`snap list` maybe needed to, but I'm guessing here actually; we can contrast the details you provide with our running systems for example anyway)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [chromium-browser: ERROR: not connected to the gnome-3-28-1804 content interface](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1327876/chromium-browser-error-not-connected-to-the-gnome-3-28-1804-content-interface)

Comment: I tried nap connections chromium and got a long list of connections

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/2025916